# How to fix wrong https in browser

Tags: html, ssl, web, https, firewall

my website https://www.startup.taipei under the https URL, there are different errors in the browser.

in **IE11**, it happens very often and needs to be refreshed several times :

> Can’t connect securely to this page. This might be because the site
>   uses outdated or unsafe TLS security settings. If this keeps
>   happening, try contacting the website’s owner.

[image: IMAGE1]

**Chrome/edge**, it happens occasionally and it also needs to be refreshed several times :

> This site can't be reached. The connection was reset.
>   (ERR_CONNECTION_RESET)

[image: IMAGE2]

**Firefox**:good work

As mentioned above, this is a big headache for our users. I have ruled out the browser issue, is there any clue on the web server?

> -Windows Server
>
> -PHP 7.2.25

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for @Scapegoat: https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747758-Force-your-site-to-load-securely-with-an-htaccess-file

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the site is supporting TLS 1.3:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect www.startup.taipei:443
...
    Protocol  : TLSv1.3
    Cipher    : TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

But it is not supporting any other TLS protocol version, i.e. no TLS 1.2 etc:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect www.startup.taipei:443 -no_tls1_3
...
write:errno=104
...
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
```

The `errno=104` means that the server has send a RST, i.e. "Connection reset by peer".

TLS 1.3 is not supported by IE 11 and it might not even be supported by the TLS stack in your unknown Windows version. Since Firefox and Chrome come with their own TLS stack which supports TLS 1.3 the connection with these will be successful.

Comment: Hi, sorry for not responding. We are trying to replace SSL certificates and will also rule out issues that do not support TLS 2.0. But the above does not seem to explain why Google Chrome still produces intermittent errors?

Comment: @Scapegoat: intermediate errors are usually a server side problem. Changing the certificate does not solve the problems since they are not related to the certificates. It is the rest of the server configuration which is the problem (supported protocols, supported ciphers). I recommend that you follow [these recommendations](https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/) when configuring the server.